# 502 bad gateway errors as provider

Tags: cloudflare-workers, rapidapi

I just added api on rapidapi, and whitelisted their IP addresses on cloudflare workers. I don't get 502 when visiting endpoint directly, but that happens when I do it with when testing endpoint in rapidapi dashboard. Cloudflare worker dashboard doesn't register any api requests from rapidapi.
[Endpoint settings in rapidapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8FXj.png)

[What it looks like when it runs successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE8lt.png)

[502 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cp1l.png)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, but rapidapi support says the base url should be available rather than just the endpoints. I attached cf worker to a endpoint route rather than the base url. I also misconfigured dns settings where non www urls didn't get past dns, which is what mustve caused errors.